# Property 'find' does not exist on type 'string' in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I get this error `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'string'.`

The way I'm running the script and detailed error:

```
$ npm run build-next

> admin-ui@1.0.0 build-next /Users/.../admin-ui
> next build

Creating an optimized production build ...


Found experimental config:
Experimental features can change at anytime and aren't officially supported (use at your own risk).

> Using external babel configuration
> Location: "/Users/.../admin-ui/.babelrc"
Failed to compile.

/Users/.../admin-ui/pages/app/signup.tsx
ERROR in /Users/.../admin-ui/pages/app/signup.tsx
76:69 Property 'find' does not exist on type 'string'.
    74 |     ]);
    75 |
  > 76 |     const forbiddenIndustryIds = industryOptions.filter(o => o.name.find('blah') !== -1).map(o => o.id.toString());
       |                                                                     ^
    77 |
    78 |     const sortedIndustryOptions = industryOptions.map(item => {
    79 |           const result: SelectOption = {

> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at build (/Users/.../admin-ui/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:6:847)
```

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

`package.json` scripts section:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build-server": "tsc --esModuleInterop server.ts",
    "build-next": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  }
```

Comment: Seems correct to me: strings don't have a method named `find`. Did you mean to use `indexOf`? Or is `name` supposed to be an array (which does have a `find`)?

Comment: Hahahah....one of those days, @NicholasTower 

Comment: We've all been there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler: +Infinity, Me: 0

`find` truly does not exist on a string! `indexOf` is what I was looking for.